# Can't find JavaFX runtime in my system

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, javafx

I installed JDK1.7 in directory D:\Programs\Java\JDK1.7\, then installed JavaFX in D:\Programs\Oracle\JavaFX_2_SDK. I use eclipse IDE with plugin e(fx)clipse etc. But I can not new a javafx project, by prompting no configured runtimes. I thought the version of plugin may be incorrcct, and downloaded the NetBeans 7.1 IDE. It still told me the current JDK platform did not support JavaFX. 
How can I configure my JavaFX runtime?

Answer (score 0):

as you didn't use standard paths IDEs are confused :)

In NetBeans:

- open Tools->Java Platforms
- click "Create New"
- select your jdk 1.7 installation
- name it "Default JavaFX Platform"
- Finish
- open JavaFX tab
- select your JavaFX SDK installation

voila

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the eclipse and jdk are all 32bit or 64bit version.

Answer (score 0):

try to install OpenJDK, it contain JavaFX and it configure automatically the path. you will also get the latest version of the program.

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```